# Events of feathersjs channels do not come through to client

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I setup a very basic Featherjs Channel following [their guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html). So on the server I have:

```
module.exports = app => {
  // If no real-time functionality has been configured just return
  if (typeof app.channel !== 'function') return

  app.on('connection', connection => {
    // On a new real-time connection, add it to the anonymous channel
    app.channel('anonymous').join(connection)
  })

  app.on('login', (authResult, {connection}) => {
    // connection can be undefined if there is no
    // real-time connection, e.g. when logging in via REST
    if (connection) {
      // Obtain the logged in user from the connection
      const {user} = connection

      // When the connection is no longer anonymous (as you the user is logged in), remove it
      app.channel('anonymous').leave(connection)

      // Add it to the authenticated user channel
      app.channel('authenticated').join(connection)
    }
  })

  app.publish((data, hook) => {
    return app.channel('authenticated')
  })

  app.service('points').publish('created', () => app.channel('authenticated'))
}
```

And in my client:

```
api.on('authenticated', response => {
  console.log('Yes, here is the event from the channel: ', response)
})
```

This setup should give all events from all my featherjs services. However I only get an event on my client when I login. When I subsequently create objects through my feathers api service, nothing is shown/ no events come through. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [authenticated event](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/client.html#apponauthenticated-callback) is a purely client side event which will be triggered when the client authenticates successfully. It is not an event that is sent from the server.

Channels only apply to [service events](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html) sent from the server. For your example this would mean using something like

```
app.service('points').on('created', point => {})
```

On the client. The client will only receive the `created` event once it has been authenticated.

Comment: Yeah, the similar naming of the channel and the specific not related authenticated event tripped me off. But it is clear now, thanks!

Comment: If there is something that can be done to make this better in the docs, feel free to create an issue or submit a PR to https://github.com/feathersjs/docs/